# Error: Activity class { } does not exist. Error while Launching activity

Tags: android-activity, launching

My simple "Hello World" app runs on the tablet Samsung gt_3113 (with Android 4.2.2), but does not work on my phone mi_4c (Android 5.1.1). I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2. Why?

**Relevant files**:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Error message

```
11/27 16:01:54: Launching app
$ adb push C:\DREAM\TestMi4\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c"
Aborted 


$ adb shell am start -n "com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c/com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c/com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c/com.adc2017gmail.testmi4c.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

I tried to reinstall the drivers,

- Cleaned the Project
- Deleted the Build directory
- Restarted Android Studio
- Rebuild the Project
- Run

Jumps from Android Studio 2.2.2 to 1.5.1

Comment: do you use a real device or emulator?

Comment: I use real devices: tablet samsung gt3113 and smartphone mi 4c

Comment: before run the project, try to uninstall the app manually in your devices and make a fresh install.

Comment: The problem is that the app runs on Android 4.2.2 (tablet). but, Android Studio 2.2.2 gives an error when run on Android 5.1.1 (mi_4c). Error: Activity class { } does not exist. Error while Launching activity

Comment: After when I created apk file and set it in mi_4c, app run (launched from Android Studio)

Comment: But if I make a change in the phrase Hello world, this is not on the screen! It turns out that Android Studio simply launches the application on my phone, but not one that is in it.

Comment: If the application is removed from the phone and run it again with Android Studio, gives the same error launch :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a devices as my LG Stylus 3 Android 7.0, in which when you press and move app from desktop to the trash, app does not removed from device. See [my answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249317/753575) for details.