# Activity class does not exist (Error type 3)

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-5x

I have a device nexus5x with android O and i develop an app in my laptop and also in another computer. But when i want to start the app in another computer after i have started it in my laptop i always get error described below.

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.safetylink.android.safetylinkheartbeatapp/com.application.aware.safetylink.auth.SplashScreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.safetylink.android.safetylinkheartbeatapp/com.application.aware.safetylink.auth.SplashScreenActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.safetylink.android.safetylinkheartbeatapp/com.application.aware.safetylink.auth.SplashScreenActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

It's a magic for me, because i don't have the same problem with another phones (it's just being reinstalled) and with emulator. Application works fine on them.

I think it's related to nexus5x settings, but i don't know exactly.
What should i do, to fix this problem?

P.S.: I have already tryed to clean, rebuild project, rename activity, invalidate cache and restart for several times, also disable instance run, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: am start  "com.safetylink.android.safetylinkheartbeatapp" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Comment: you don't need to specify Activity / service when you are using action and category. it will be resolved by android.

Comment: @RahulKumar, sorry, i didn't understand you. My first activity in manifest is:

`<activity
            android:name="com.application.aware.safetylink.auth.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I mean your am command should not have -n option and you can only give package name and action and category. You don’t have to give the class name (component name) while using am in adb

Comment: @RahulKumar, i didn't config any special options for adb. In configurations -> launch options i have a "Default activity" and don't have any specific flags. i don't know where is "-n options", i don't configured it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On some devices (LG Stylus 3 Android 7.0) when you press and move app from desktop to trash can the **app does not removed** from device. You can restore app trashed by this way later without reinstalling it from Google Play. If it is your case you may see this error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "ru.alanov.cashbox/ru.alanov.cashbox.activity.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.your.app/.activity.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {ru.alanov.cashbox/com.your.app.activity.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

when trying to reinstall app from Android Studio thru ADB. Go to Settings -> Applications -> Click on your app and delete it. After it error disappears.

Comment: Thank you! 
I have wasted a lot of time with it "Error type 3".
May be do you know how can i configure my smartphone to remove apps directly by "press and moving to trash" ???

Comment: I would like to know it too :) What is your device and Android version?

Comment: i'm usng Nexus5x with Android O.
But it's really strange, that in the application settings apps doesn't remove. If i remove it with ADB command or with "moving to trash" it just marks as "didn't installed" in application settings.

Comment: What ? My app is no longer on the Application List in Settings. Any idea ? I already tried to restart both device and Android Studio.

Comment: Happens in Nokia phones too! Try removing other users on your phone

Comment: No app listed in the application list, but using `adb uninstall <package_name>` works, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting this error, it may be because the app that you are trying to load is still installed for another user account on the same device.

In other words, uninstalling an app for the current user account does not necessarily uninstall the same app for all other user accounts on the device.

If you go into Settings => App and look for the device in question, you will see that it may still be there.  If that is the case, Tap on the app to show the App Info screen and goto the "..." overflow menu on the upper right hand side.  Tap that and there should be an option to uninstall the app for all users.

Once you have uninstalled the app for all users, this error should go away and you should be able to load and run the app.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue with my project. I resolve it by navigating to **file** and clicking on **Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the installation of the "**Deploy: Default APK**" [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xuLG.png) in Android Studio was helpful

Comment: If you have tried all other options (including [these](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14952)), but the problem still remains. Then most likely you just do not update the apk on the target device. One of the reasons why it may not be updated is incorrect settings in the IDE

Comment: This helped me as the only thing out of MANY that i tried!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there are lot of possible issues that causes this error. In my case I had changed the Installation options (see below steps to know where is Installation options) to "APK from app bundle"

Here is how I resolved it. May be helpful for someone.

1. In AndroidStudio (AS) under "Run" Toolbar/Menu select "Edit configurations" menu item.
2. In the Run/Debug Configuration popup Window, under "Android App" select "app"
3. To the rightside, under "General" tab check if Module: app is selected.
4. Under "Installation Options", "Deploy: " was selected wrongly. Selected back to"Default APK" and everything worked properly there after.

[Installation Option Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVDWS.png)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and this is how I fixed it.

Go to Gradle > Tasks > Install > UninstallAll

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot to above answers, I guess in my case the issue was with Redmi devices running on MIUI which supports Second Space.

I had it enabled which was causing problems with uninstalling previous installation thereby troubling  new install, btw I had also tried to manually copy the APK to sdcard install it, which also failed saying "App cant be installed".

So if anyone like me is using MIUI please double check Second space is enabled when you are getting this error and your app is not available in Settings->Apps and Launcher.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to uninstall the app with adb command

```
adb shell pm uninstall <packageName>
```

If it didn't work you can try this

```
./gradlew uA
```

If none of them work then you can try to build an apk and put it your phone via cable. It should work like this.

Answer (score 1):

On the phone having the problem go to:
Settings Apps.  If you see the app in the list select it and uninstall from there.

Seems as if just drag to uninstall doesn't really uninstall it.

Another great android feature

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this problem is to download and install Android studio on other laptop/PC and the requirements for connecting android to laptop/PC and then follow the same procedure for running the app on mobile. It is lengthy procedure, but if you don't understand the other solutions to this answer, I recommend you to follow the following. They may be lengthy but they work completely fine. Because it did work for me. The app which had been deleted gets installed again and you programs will run completely fine on connecting to the laptop/ PC which you used first.