# Android Studio - MainActivity does not exist even on NEW project

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I posted a question regarding a null pointer I have been receiving in android studio relating to Context that was always null in addition this error keeps showing up no matter how I tried to assign it.

I have not been able to find a solution to this problem so decided to start an entirely new project - without writing a single line of code I am getting the same error.

Console Error

```
$ adb shell am start -n "za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler/za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler/za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler/za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

AndroidManifest.xml (UNTOUCHED)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

gradle project file (UNTOUCHED)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle app file (UNTOUCHED)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

MainActivity.java (UNTOUCHED)

```
package za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: clean-rebuild-restart ide

Comment: I have done that - as well as invalidate/restart and i have also cleaned gradle files no change

Comment: `import za.co.freelanceweb.scheduler.R;`

Comment: Tried import no luck - thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888298/activity-class-does-not-exist-error-type-3 check if this answer might help  you

Comment: update your android studio version or delete the cache folder in your location:
C:\Users\thesmzh\.AndroidStudio3.6\system\caches 
before deleting close android studio and after done restart the studio

Comment: THANK YOU Android_id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888298/activity-class-does-not-exist-error-type-3 This worked

Answer (score -1):

[Delete this Three folder and restart android Studio . Doing this will not delete your old project.
But don't delete the Android Studio project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEI2Q.jpg)

Comment: I tried this no luck - thanks.